# Change Cognito Forms billing detail

Tags: cognito-forms

I received an email stating our billing failed. We have a new credit card as of yesterday and probably need to change it on our account. I will need to know where to change the card on the account.

Comment: Two notes: This is a support request you need to direct to Cognito directly; this is a site of volunteers answering questions on all kinds of web applications. Second, on the Internet, ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service issue with Cognito Forms and should be addressed to them directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](http://cognitoforms.com).

You can change your Billing Information by going to your Organization Settings. You can learn more about this process in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/192/account--organizations/plans--billing/changing-your-billing-information).

Comment: Do you think you could craft up a question/answer to cover questions of a support nature that we could keep around as the canonical solution and so close questions such as this as a duplicate?